# How to remove field conditionally mongoodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection and its documents look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('111111111122222222223333'),
  my_array: [
    {
      id: ObjectId('777777777788888888889999')
      name: 'foo'
    },
    {
      id: ObjectId('77777777778888888888555')
      name: 'foo2'
    }
    //...
  ]
  //more attributes
}
```

However, some documents have `my_array: [{}]` (with one element which is an empty array).

How can I add conditionally a projection or remove it?

I have to add it to a mongo pipeline at the end of the query, and I want to get *my_array* only when it has at least one element which is not an empty object. If there's an empty object remove it.

I tried with `$cond` and `$eq` in a projection stage but it is not supported. Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried: `{ my_array: { $exists: true, $type: 'array', $eq: [{}] } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in a `query`, however in an aggregations you can add [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to you pipeline, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      my_array: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$my_array",
          as: "elem",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {},
              "$$elem"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fu7q3ImWVN3)

However unless this is "correct" behavior I suggest you clean up your database, it's much simpler to maintain "proper" structure than to update all your queries everywhere.

You can use this update to remove these objects:

```
db.collection.update({
  "myarray": {}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "my_array": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$my_array",
          as: "elem",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {},
              "$$elem"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
],
{
  "multi": false,
  "upsert": false
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B1ErAchoq8b)

Comment: Thank you! I need this because the pipeline i am using builds this array with empty object but it is not stored into a DB! gg

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have documents like this with `my_array` field:

```
{ "my_array" : [ ] }
{ "my_array" : [ { "a" : 1 } ] }    // #(1)
{ "my_array" : null }
{ "some_fld" : "some value" }
{ "my_array" : [ {  } ] }
{ "my_array" : [ { "a" : 2 }, { "a" : 3 } ] }    // #(2)
```

And, the following aggregation will filter and the result will have the *two* documents `(1)` and `(2)`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: { 
      $expr: {
          $and: [ 
              { $eq: [ { $type: "$my_array" }, "array" ] },
              { $gt: [ { $size: "$my_array" }, 0 ] }, 
              { $ne: [ [{}], "$my_array" ] }
          ]
      }
  } 
}
])
```

This also works with a `find` method:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
          $and: [ 
              { $eq: [ { $type: "$my_array" }, "array" ] },
              { $gt: [ { $size: "$my_array" }, 0 ] }, 
              { $ne: [ [{}], "$my_array" ] }
          ]
      }
})
```

To remove the `my_array` field, from a document when its empty, then you try this aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $addFields: { 
      my_array: {
          $cond: [
              {$and: [ 
                  { $eq: [ { $type: "$my_array" }, "array" ] },
                  { $gt: [ { $size: "$my_array" }, 0 ] }, 
                  { $ne: [ [{}], "$my_array" ] }
              ]}, 
              "$my_array", 
              "$$REMOVE"
          ]
      }
  } 
}
])
```

The result:

```
{  }
{ "my_array" : [ { "a" : 1 } ] }
{  }
{ "a" : 1 }
{  }
{ "my_array" : [ { "a" : 2 }, { "a" : 3 } ] }
```